# ETS table - Updating maps as records

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

Sample code:

```
defmodule Foo do

  def fast_cars_cache do
    fast_cars = 
    {
      %{color: "Red", make: "Mclaren", mileage: 15641.469},
      %{color: "Blue", make: "Ferrari", mileage: 120012.481},
      %{color: "Red", make: "Ferrari", mileage: 29831.021},
      %{color: "Black", make: "Ferrari", mileage: 24030.674},
      %{color: "Cobalt", make: "Ferrari", mileage: 412.811},
      %{color: "Blue", make: "Koenigsegg", mileage: 250.762},
      %{color: "Cobalt", make: "Koenigsegg", mileage: 1297.76}, 
      %{color: "Titanium", make: "Koenigsegg", mileage: 5360.336},
      %{color: "Blue", make: "Maserati", mileage: 255.78}
    }

    if Enum.member?(:ets.all(), :fast_cars_cache) do
      :ets.delete(:fast_cars_cache)
      :ets.new(:fast_cars_cache, [:duplicate_bag, :public, :named_table])
      :ets.insert(:fast_cars_cache, fast_cars)
    else
      :ets.new(:fast_cars_cache, [:duplicate_bag, :public, :named_table])
      :ets.insert(:fast_cars_cache, fast_cars)
    end
  end


  def update_record do
    fast_cars_cache()

    old_record = :ets.first(:fast_cars_cache)

    new_record = 
    %{color: "Black", make: old_record.make, mileage: 1641.469}

    :ets.delete(:fast_cars_cache, {old_record})
    |> IO.inspect(label: "Old record deleted")

    :ets.insert(:fast_cars_cache, {new_record})
    :ets.tab2list(:fast_cars_cache)
  end

end
```

Output:

```
iex(1)> Foo.update_record
Old record deleted: true
[
  {%{color: "Red", make: "Mclaren", mileage: 15641.469},
   %{color: "Blue", make: "Ferrari", mileage: 120012.481},
   %{color: "Red", make: "Ferrari", mileage: 29831.021},
   %{color: "Black", make: "Ferrari", mileage: 24030.674},
   %{color: "Cobalt", make: "Ferrari", mileage: 412.811},
   %{color: "Blue", make: "Koenigsegg", mileage: 250.762},
   %{color: "Cobalt", make: "Koenigsegg", mileage: 1297.76},
   %{color: "Titanium", make: "Koenigsegg", mileage: 5360.336},
   %{color: "Blue", make: "Maserati", mileage: 255.78}},
  {%{color: "Black", make: "Mclaren", mileage: 1641.469}}
]
```

Observations/Questions:

1. According to the `IO.inspect`, `old_record` was deleted yet, as `tab2list` reveals, this record still exists. Why is that?
2. If, in fact, `old_record` was never deleted, what adjustments does the code need to accomplish this?
3. Ideally, I'd like to make use of `:ets.select_replace`, if applicable, to perform this update all in one step but I can't make heads or tails of the [stipulations](https://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html) for the match specification requirement. It'd be really helpful if someone could disambiguate it with an example or two based on the sample above.

As always, thanks so much for your helpful guidance and suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clearly distinguish maps and tuples. [`Map`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html?) is a key-value structure. [`Tuple`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Tuple.html?) is not.

**`:ets` records are tuples, not maps.**

Your initial structure is a tuple of maps. One single tuple, having many maps. It gets inserted as a single element into `:ets`, which is clearly visible in your output (check curly braces.)

I would guess you were to insert *many* elements into the cache.

```rb
iex|1 ▶ :ets.new(:fast_cars_cache, [:duplicate_bag, :public, :named_table])
iex|2 ▶ fast_cars = [
...|2 ▶   {"Red", "Mclaren", 15641.469},
...|2 ▶   {"Blue", "Ferrari", 120012.481},
...|2 ▶   {"Red", "Ferrari", 29831.021}
...|2 ▶ ]
iex|3 ▶ :ets.insert(:fast_cars_cache, fast_cars)
```

[`:ets.first/1`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#first-1), as it’s stated in the documentation, returns *the first key*. [`:ets.detele/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#delete-2) deletes a record *by key* and your code wraps whatever was returned from `:ets.first/1` into a one-element tuple, making `:ets.delete/2` a no-op no matter what (and yes, `:ets.delete/2` *always* returns `true`.)

```rb
iex|4 ▶ :ets.first(:fast_cars_cache)
#⇒ "Red"
iex|5 ▶ :ets.delete(:fast_cars_cache, {"Red"}) # NOOP
#⇒ true
iex|6 ▶ :ets.delete(:fast_cars_cache, "Red") # DELETED
#⇒ true
```

Then if you want to insert a new record, create a tuple and insert it, don’t create a map wrapped into a single-element tuple. To get the old record by key, one usually uses [`:ets.lookup/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#lookup-2), or more sophisticated `:ets.select`.

```rb
iex|7 ▶ [{_, make, _}|_] = :ets.lookup(:fast_cars_cache, "Red")
iex|8 ▶ new_record = {"Black", make, 1641.469}
iex|9 ▶ :ets.insert(:fast_cars_cache, new_record)
```

I have linked enough documentation to leave using [`:ets.select_replace/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#select_replace-2) as homework.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation. You're a great teacher! One last question, how can I get :ets.delete to not report "true" when it fails?

Answer (score 2):

As Aleksei said, you can also use the `:ets.select_replace/2` function.
Here's an example:

```
:ets.new :t0, [:set, :public, :named_table]
:ets.insert :t0, {{:foo, [:a, :b]}, {:ok, :c}, [ttl: :os.system_time(:seconds) - 1]}
:ets.insert :t0, {{:boo, [:d, :e]}, {:ok, :g}, [ttl: :os.system_time(:seconds) - 1]}

new_opt = {{:new_opt, :this_is_new_opt}}
ms = [{
  patter = {key = {:boo, :"$1"}, :"$2", [ttl: :"$3"]}, 
  where = [{:<, :"$3", :os.system_time(:seconds)}], 
  replace = [{{
    key = {{:boo, :"$1"}}, 
    new_value0 = {{:ok, :replaced}}, 
    new_value1 = [
      {{:ttl, :os.system_time(:seconds)}}, 
      new_opt
    ]
  }}]
}]

:ets.select_replace :t0, ms
:ets.tab2list :t0
```

Writing it wholly by hands seems little annoying, instead of it you can hack it just using `:ets.fun2ms/1` and then copy past it and adding your variables in the generated `matchSpec`.

```
ms = :ets.fun2ms(fn {{:boo, a}, b, [ttl: c]} = x when c > 1700807468 ->
  {{:boo, a}, b, [ttl: c, new: :new]} 
end)
```

Note:

- you cannot use the `:ets.select_replace/2` in order to replace key, this mean you cannot replace `{:boo, [:d, :e]}`;
- you cannot use the `:ets.fun2ms/1` function in an Elixir module, this function is available only in shell;
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973892/13836308) maybe useful if you want to use `:ets.fun2ms/1` in your codebase;